# How to add user-defined words to spaCy

Tags: spacy, tokenize

I am a novice of spaCy and am using spaCy to process medical literature. I found that Tokenizer would divide the Latin name composed of two words into two independent words, which is inappropriate. In addition, I have thousands of customized words, which are basically biological names (usually composed of two words, such as Angelica sinensis). How can I add these customized words to spaCy and let Tokenizer recognize these multi-word words as a single token without splitting them. Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the docs regarding [tokenization](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#tokenization)? Especially the section about [adding special case rules](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases)?

Comment: @Rafael-WO Yes, I read this part before posting. In addition, I wrote the following code according to the instructions in the document: import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

# Add special case rule
special_case = [{ORTH: "Angelica sinensis"}]
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case("Angelica sinensis", special_case)

doc = nlp("Here are some Angelica sinensis.")
print([w.text for w in doc])

output:['Here', 'are', 'some', 'Angelica sinensis', '.']

Comment: @Rafael-WO I'm not sure. Is this the usual way for spaCy to add user-defined dictionaries? Because I have thousands of user-defined words, I need to use a loop to add these thousands of user-defined words in this way? Is such efficiency a little low? I'm a novice. I don't know if there is a better way to add user-defined dictionaries.

Comment: I think this is your question on the spaCy forums? https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/12007

Comment: Also, it's better if you edit your question if you need to add code - it's too hard to read code in comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of multi-word expressions that you would like to treat as tokens, the easiest thing to do is use an [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) to mark them as entities and then use the [`merge_entitites`](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities) component.